# Form of saving an image in Qt

Tags: forms, qt, user-interface, save

I'm designing a GUI in Qt and I need to use a form to save an image. The user would be able to save a file in any location (a simple save form that we see under *Save as...*). How can make a save-as form in Qt?
thanks!

Comment: Look at documentation: http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtwidgets-tutorials-addressbook-part6-example.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do, for example, the following:

```
QImage image(128, 128);
image.fill(Qt::red); // A red rectangle.
QString fileName = QFileDialog::getSaveFileName(this, tr("Save Image File"),
                                                QString(),
                                                tr("Images (*.png)"));
if (!fileName.isEmpty())
{
  image.save(fileName);
}
```

Comment: What do you mean? For instance, you can set `"Image Files (*.png *.jpg *.bmp)"` as a filter in the dialog. Or you mean how to save image in different formats?

Comment: i found that with ;; i can let the user to select his format. how to detect the format user selected?

Comment: @javad, you can use `QFileDialog::selectedNameFilter()` function that will return the selected filter.